# Input[] inside DynamicModule causing a kernel crash

Tags: dynamic, crash

I have those few lines of code causing a crash and I can't figure out why:

```
DynamicModule[{openNothing},
 EventHandler[
  Panel@Row@{
     Button["Built In Funct", openNothing[]]}, {}],

 Initialization :> (openNothing[] := (Input["bla", 1];))]
```

*Mathematica* freezes for a few seconds and then says:

> The kernel is not responding to a Dynamic Evaluation. [...]

**WARNING:** It did make *Mathematica* not responding at all. After the **force quit** the list of the recently opened notebooks were removed (I assume that the `~/.Mathematica/FrontEnd/init.m` has been removed.)

I'm on *Fedora 19*, *Mathematica* 8.0.4. The same issue has been noticed under *Windows 7*, *Mathematica* 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
DynamicModule[{openNothing}, 
 Dynamic@Panel@
   Row@{Button["Built In Funct", openNothing[], Method -> "Queued"]}, 
 Initialization :> (openNothing[] := (Input["bla", 1];))]
```

Comment: Read the docs on the "Queued" Method. Also you dont realky need EventHandler.